# Git Merge Instructions not Work as Expected

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have just tried following [these Atlassian Bitbucket instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html) for resolving merge conflicts and found that it doesn't work correctly.

If these instructions are followed then sometimes changes in the "develop" branch will overwrite changes made in the "source branch".

For example in a Swift file (note that these are two versions and the line numbers are included):

this is develop and git is trying to keep this one.

```
required init?(map: Map){ // 67
    super.init()          // 68
    mapping(map: map)     // 69
    if origin == nil {    // 70
        origin = ""       // 71
    }                     // 72
}                         // 73
```

this is source file

```
required init?(map: Map){  // 67
    super.init()           // 68
    mapping(map: map)      // 69
}                          // 70
```

As you can see the "source branch" has these lines of code deleted but git thinks "develop" should add them back in again. (rightly so if I'm telling develop to merge into my branch as per Atlassian instructions)

This is incorrect as everything in my branch should attempt to overwrite every file/change in the develop branch and raise a conflict if there is one.

Am I going noob or are these instructions incorrect?

Also can someone suggest conflict resolution that uses my branch as the be all and end all?

(I think that I need to have "develop" checked out and then merge the "feature branch" into that. Get the feeling that this skips the pull request step though...do not want)

Comment: No, we cannot "see" that anything has been deleted from what you are showing. To see that, we need to know what has changed and where, as well as which branch is merging into what branch. The only time one generally gets merge conflicts is when edits were made to same or adjacent lines of code.

Comment: @crashmstr I added line numbers and split the two files into separate code blocks for clarity.

Comment: Are you merging `source` into `develop` and that file and those lines *did not change* in `develop`? Also, if you are going to do a pull request, you don't merge these manually. The pull request will do that after approval.

Comment: I have a pull request up to merge source into develop. This has a conflict. The instructions say to merge develp into source in order to resolve the conflicts then update the pull request.

Comment: Then select your changes to be used or select your version of the whole file to be used. This *should* only happen if the lines or adjacent lines were changed, and in that case, using *only* your version could lose valid changes from the other branch.

Comment: A conflict is a situation when a line or a set of lines is modified in different ways on the branches that one wants to merge. Git cannot solve it automatically because it cannot guess the authors' intentions, that's why it stops and waits for the user to decide. The instructions provided by the Atlassian website teach you how to use Git to get one version of the file or the other but the decision about what lines to keep is entirely yours (step #5).

Comment: @axiac the code I'm showing in the example is not a conflict. The problem is that git wants to keep the lines of in the develop branch which I delete in the source branch. (It doesn't ask to resolve any conflict at all). I think those lines of code I'm showing should have resulted in a conflict.

Comment: As I said before, a conflict happens when the same line is modified in both branches in different ways. "Modified" includes deletion. Since you modified those lines only in the "develop" branch and not in the "source" branch then there is no conflict. Why do you need to follow the instructions about how to solve merge conflicts if there is no conflict?

Comment: @axiac I checked this branch out of develop and it had those lines it. I have the commit in my "source" branch where I deleted those lines. It is commit "a65f93b". In summary, I checked out develop with the if statement then I deleted the if statement and now I'm merging back into develop and git decides that the if statement should stay.

Comment: I've obviously done something noob here but this isolated issue with that Swift file (an some others) confuses me.

Comment: Correcting myself on that comment, I'm merging develop into my source branch as per the instructions and this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the develop branch had a "reversion" done on it after the source branch had been branched and checked out. This gave the develop branch a higher priority in history and git will therefore reject any changes in my branch. (all 20 file and who knows how many lines of code)

Speaking with a coworker it turns out the reversion was done because of an accidental merge into the origin/develop.

Simple rule - Do no use "reverse commit to" if other developers have branches with changes.

Doing that^ overwrites every single change done to other developers local branches when they merge XD